# How to move the figure viewpoint to a 3d position, looking along a vector?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am plotting a 3d point cloud, but am having difficulty rotating the figure into a certain pose.

For example,

```
figure; hold on;

z = linspace(0,3*pi,250);
x = 2*cos(z) + rand(1,250);
y = 2*sin(z) + rand(1,250);

plot3(x, y, z, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 20);

plot3(x(1), y(1), z(1), 'kx', 'MarkerSize', 20);
plot3([x(1) x(end)], [y(1) y(end)], [z(1) z(end)], '-k');
```

The default perspective is

[image: Figure showing point cloud]

I want to look along the black line from the 'X' position. I can manually rotate the figure with the GUI controls, and I find that I get closest at Azimuth 96 Elevation -46

[image: Rotated Figure]

I can rotate the view to this position using

```
view(96, -46);
```

However, the viewpoint isn't actually positioned on top of the 'X'. 'X' is some distance in front of the viewpoint. Additionally, I have a different vector every time I call this code, so I can't use the same azimuth and elevation every time.

I should be able to calculate the azimuth and elevation from the vector. My attempt,

```
x_dif = x(end)- x(1);
y_dif = y(end)-y(1);
z_dif = z(end)-z(1);

azimuth = (atan(x_dif/y_dif))*180/pi;
elevation = (atan(z_dif/sqrt(x_dif^2+y_dif^2)))*180/pi;
view(azimuth, elevation);
```

This produces an incorrect solution. I think it may be because the azimuth and elevation should be relative to the center of the plot box. ([`view` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html?s_tid=srchtitle)). I'm not sure how to do this.

How can I calculate and apply a rotation to the figure given the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view` has an option to use a cartisian direction `[x,y,z]` rather than `[alt,azi]`.

This works for me: *(Please note the `axis equal` call to avoid deformations in the default `plot` axis scaling)*

```
function cecilia()
    figure; hold on;

    z = linspace(0,3*pi,250);
    x = 2*cos(z) + rand(1,250);
    y = 2*sin(z) + rand(1,250);

    plot3(x, y, z, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 20);

    plot3(x(1), y(1), z(1), 'kx', 'MarkerSize', 20);
    plot3([x(1) x(end)], [y(1) y(end)], [z(1) z(end)], '-k');

    x_dif = x(end)- x(1);
    y_dif = y(end)-y(1);
    z_dif = z(end)-z(1);

    view([x_dif,y_dif,z_dif]);
    axis equal
end
```

You should see the following result:

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: Guess I just overlooked this in the documentation. Good find!

Comment: No worries, the documentation buries it. I think your `[alt,az]` code might have worked too with `axis equal` though your should use `atand()` rather than `atan()*180/pi()`.